# How to use the plotly function in plotly package of R?

Tags: r, plotly

I am tring check if I have a username and API key with:

```
plotly:::verify("Macrosummer")
```

but the function return the information as below:

```
[1] ""
Warning message:
Couldn't find Macrosummer
```

And I try to verify the API key with the code as :

```
plotly:::verify("6yvu16vlkv")
```

the function return the information as below:

```
[1] ""
Warning message:
Couldn't find 6yvu16vlkv
```

How to get the right result?

Answer (score 0):

For the verify commands you can run as written in the installation [instructions][1] i.e. `plotly:::verify("username")` (no need to use YOUR username/api key). This should then return YOUR username.

Comment: Thank you.This instruction only have a effect after we set the environment by the code as below:
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="xxxx")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="xxxxx")
but I couldn't understand why we should set it?